# Trying to tranpose matrix using pointer arithmetic

Tags: c, debugging, matrix

I am trying to write a program that
takes inputs on the amount of rows and columns
of a given matrix. Then I would like to ask the user to input the values on each indice, then print out the array.

I accomplished this by doing:

```
int main() {
    int rows, columns;
    int i, j;
    printf("Enter amount of rows: ");
    scanf("%d", &rows);
    printf("Enter amount of columns: ");
    scanf("%d", &columns);
   
    int array[rows][columns];
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < columns; j++){
            printf("Enter element of row %d and column %d: ", i + 1, j + 1);
            scanf("%d", &array[i][j]);
        }
    }
   
    printf("You entered:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            if (j == 0)
                printf("[ ");
            printf("%d ", array[i][j]);
            if (j == columns - 1)
                printf("]\n");
        }
    }
    printf("-----------------------------\n");
```

This part of the code gives expected output. Whenever the amount of rows and columns are the same, I get my expected output as well. e.g:

```
You entered:
[ 1 2 3 ]
[ 4 5 6 ]
[ 7 8 9 ]
-----------------------------
Transposed matrix:
[ 1 4 7 ]
[ 2 5 8 ]
[ 3 6 9 ]
```

Whenever there are more columns than rows, I get expected output as well.

```
You entered:
[ 1 2 3 4 5 ]
[ 6 7 8 9 10 ]
[ 11 12 13 14 15 ]
-----------------------------
Transposed matrix:
[ 1 6 11 ]
[ 2 7 12 ]
[ 3 8 13 ]
[ 4 9 14 ]
[ 5 10 15 ]
```

However, whenever there are more rows than columns, that's where the issue seems to arise.
For example:

```
You entered:
[ 1 2 ]
[ 3 4 ]
[ 5 6 ]
-----------------------------
Transposed matrix:
[ 1 3 2 ]
[ 2 4 5 ]
```

This is the code responsible for the transposing. It is right under the print statement with multiple dashes. Any help or insight as to why this isn't working would be great.

```
for (i = 0; i < columns; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            int *transposedRow = &array[0][0] + (i * columns + j);
            int *transposedCol = &array[0][0] + (j * columns + i);
            int temp;
            temp = *transposedRow;
            *transposedRow = *transposedCol;
            *transposedCol = temp;
        }
    }
    printf("Transposed matrix:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
            if (j == 0)
                printf("[ ");
            printf("%d ", array[i][j]);
            if (j == rows - 1)
                printf("]\n");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Now would be a good time to learn to use a debugger. You have nicely described what testing you have done and have found a case that doesn't work. So now debug it. Step thru the code in a debugger and find out where things start going wrong.

Comment: ***However, whenever there are more rows than columns*** you cannot modify the array in-place in this case since the dimensions of matrix after transpose will be different.

Comment: Breaking this out into a separate function would likely be very useful. Incorporating @kiner_shah's suggestion about modifying in-place, a signature like: `void transpose(int *dest, int *src, size_t rows, size_t cols)` would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be thrifty on your memory (by not allocating another storage for the transpose matrix), then just do the following:

```
void print(int **matrix, size_t rows, size_t cols)
{
    for (size_t row = 0; row < rows; ++row) {
        printf("[ ");
        for (size_t col = 0; col < cols; ++col)
            print("%d ", matrix[row][col]);
        printf("]\n");
    }
}

void print_transposed(int **matrix, size_t rows, size_t cols)
{
    for (size_t col = 0; col < cols; ++col) {
        printf("[ ");
        for (size_t row = 0; row < rows; ++row)
            print("%d ", matrix[row][col]);
        printf("]\n");
    }
}
```

or if two functions are too much, combine them into one:

```
void print(int **matrix, size_t rows, size_t cols, bool transposed) {
    if (transposed) {
        /* print transposed */
    } else {
        /* print normal */
    }
}
```

No pointer arithmetic, no extra allocation, pure, simple and clean.

Comment: This is a valid approach. Don't modify anything. Just perform operations on the matrix _as though you had_. This is more memory efficient, but for repeated operations on a matrix it may require more computation, and it forces every operation on a matrix to have a `transposed` flag.

Comment: @Chris I agree, as said before, if you do not want extra allocation, then you have to pay the price via computation, you can't have both.

Answer (score 0):

If transposing in-place is not a requirement, the problem is very straightforward. You seem to have mostly figured the math out. Breaking it down into functions makes it easier to tackle pieces of this problem.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void transpose(int *dest, int *src, size_t rows, size_t cols) {
    for (size_t r = 0; r < rows; ++r)
        for (size_t c = 0; c < cols; ++c)
            *(dest + c * rows + r) = *(src + r * cols + c);
}

void print(int *matrix, size_t rows, size_t cols) {
    for (size_t r = 0; r < rows; ++r) {
        for (size_t c = 0; c < cols; ++c)
            printf("%d ", *(matrix + r * cols + c));

        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int orig[2][3] = {
        { 1, 2, 3 },
        { 4, 5, 6 }
    };

    int transposed[3][2];

    transpose(transposed, orig, 2, 3);

    print(orig, 2, 3);
    print(transposed, 3, 2);

    return 0;
}
```

Running this simple test gives us:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
1 4
2 5
3 6
```

This solution isn't perfect. There are numerous warnings about passing arrays, but I will leave that for you to learn from and figure out.